# Inserting integers from a text file to an integer array

Tags: c++, arrays, file, fstream

I have a text file filled with some integers and I want to insert these numbers to an integer array from this text file.

```
 #include <iostream>
 #include <fstream>

 using namespace std;

 int main(){

  ifstream file("numbers.txt");
  int nums[1000];

  if(file.is_open()){

     for(int i = 0; i < 1000; ++i)
     {
        file >> nums[i];
     }
  }

  return 0;
}
```

And, my text file contains integers line by line like:

```
102
220
22
123
68
```

When I try printing the array with a single loop, it prints lots of "0" in addition to the integers inside the text file.

Comment: Use a `std::vector<int>` to make your life easier.

Comment: "When I try printing the array" - the code you showed us doesn't do this. How does it look?

Comment: @JesperJuhl just a for loop that prints numbers till the end of the array with cout << nums[i]

Comment: @BK. How do you determine the end? Same way as you're doing for the input? Please always provide a [MCVE] that reproduces your problem. Best you add the code for output also.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ exactly.

Comment: _"When I try printing the array with a single loop, it prints lots of "0" in addition to the integers inside the text file."_ Well, you have 1000 integers. Not sure what else you expected.

Comment: [Works for me](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/abe04ecb4a46b7dd). Propably an issue with your input file?

Comment: @zett42 I will check. Thank you so much!

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I mean text file does not contain 0 value but when I try printing the array , output contains 0 values in addition to the integers  inside the text file. I will check the text file. Thanks for the comment.

Comment: @BK.: Again, why is this not expected? You print all the values from an array of 1000 integers. Unless your file has 1000 values, only some of those integers in the array were replaced with values from your file. The remainder are still whatever they began as (which could be 0 or something else; it's unspecified)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Always check the result of text formatted extraction:

```
if(!(file >> insertion[i])) {
    std::cout "Error in file.\n";
}
```

---

Can it be the problem is your text file doesn't contain 1000 numbers?

I'd recommend to use a `std::vector<int>` instead of a fixed sized array:

```
 #include <iostream>
 #include <fstream>
 #include <vector>

 using namespace std;

 int main(){

  ifstream file("numbers.txt");
  std::vector<int> nums;

  if(file.is_open()){
     int num;
     while(file >> num) {
         nums.push_back(num);
     }
  }

  for(auto num : nums) {
      std::cout << num << " ";
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: I am sure the file contains 1000 integers. Thanks for the suggestion. I will try this approach.